# How to use a computer to give guesses for a counting formula, given the first few terms?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Are there any systematic approaches developed on how to derive some "succinct" combinatorial formulas e.g. using factorials/hypergeometric terms and polynomials with integer coefficients that fit the first few terms of a given integer counting sequence? Perhaps a database of known sequences and formulas is also provided, so e.g. it could be detected if a sequence seems to be double or the square of another sequence with a known formula. It seems like it would be very useful if a mathematician could get some automatically generated proposals for a counting formula, and see if any of them "make sense" as relates to the counting problem so the formula can then be proved.

Comment: Like https://oeis.org/ ?

Comment: OEIS is a database but as far as I know, it doesn't detect whether a given sequence is a simple transform of another sequence. So sure, we can assume OEIS is provided but I'm asking more for algorithmic techniques to derive proposed "succinct" formulas given a sequence and given some known formulas, e.g. factorials and OEIS formulas.

Comment: @user2566092: Some CAS program (like Mathematica) have some functionality like that, but I doubt it is as thorough as you are looking for.

Comment: OEIS does have a feature called "superseeker" that can potentially detect if a sequence is a transform of a sequence already in the database. (See https://oeis.org/superhelp.txt for a list of transforms applied.) May not be exactly what you're looking for but it's good to know about at least.

Comment: You can check if it appears to obey a linear recurrence relation.  See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255025/what-are-some-strategies-for-creating-linear-recurrence-relationships/) question, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The term used is "guessing".

Given $n$ points you can fit a polynomial of degree $n-1$ through them. If that polynomial turns out to have degree much less than $n-1$ then you have a plausible guess for a formula for the sequence.

The same idea can be generalised to other types of function. The old well-known names in the field are [RATE](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/rate/rate.html) (by Christian Krattenthaler, for Mathematica) and [gfun](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/bruno.salvy/software/the-gfun-package/) (by Bruno Salvy and Paul Zimmermann, for Maple). There are many more recent packages; see, for example, the references in [The Holonomic Toolkit](http://www.algebra.uni-linz.ac.at/people/mkauers/publications/kauers13.pdf), Manuel Kauers, Computer Algebra in Quantum Field Theory, Springer,  2013, pp.119-144.